# RSA encryption python not working with small primes

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography, rsa, modular-arithmetic

I have implemented RSA encryption and decryption code which is working for values `p,q,d = 61,53,17`. I took these values as they are mentioned in wikipedia. I beleive that p and q should be prime and d is chosen such that d and phi(n) are relatively prime.

If I change the values to `p,q,d = 3,17,19`, my decryption is not working. Can you please help me with this? Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def main():
    str = 'computer'
    p,q,d = 61,53,17
    #p,q,d = 3,17,19
    cipher_text = list()
    plain_text = list()

    for c in str:
        cipher_char = EncryptCharRSA(c, p, q ,d)
        cipher_text.append(cipher_char)


    for x in cipher_text:
        plain_char = DecryptCharRSA(x, p, q, d)    
        plain_text.append(plain_char)

    print ('Original Message: ', str)

    print ('Encrypted Message(UTF-8 Unicode characters) : ', end='')
    for element in cipher_text:
        print(element,end = '')

    print ('\nDecrypted Message: ', end='')
    for element in plain_text:
        print(element,end='')

def EncryptCharRSA(msg , p, q, d):
    n = p * q
    phi = (p-1) * (q-1)            
    cipher_no = 0
    cipher_char = ''

    for c in msg:
        # conver char to ascii for calculation
        cipher_no = (ord(c)** d) % n
        cipher_char = chr(cipher_no) 
        return cipher_char   
        #print (cipher_no)
        #plain_no = (cipher_no ** d) % n

def DecryptCharRSA(msg,p, q,d):
    n = p * q
    phi = (p-1) * (q-1)
    e = ModularMultiplicativeInverse(d,phi)
    for c in msg:
        plain_no = (ord(c) ** e) % n
        plain_char = chr(plain_no)
        return plain_char   

# Get modular multiplicative inverse
def ModularMultiplicativeInverse(d,n):
    i = 1
    while True:
        if (d * i) % n == 1:
         return i
        i = i + 1

if __name__ == '__main__' : main()
```

Comment: Is the `return` inside of the `for` loops intentional?

Comment: Yes. After encrypting / decrypting a character, I am returning a character to the main() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you call `d` is actually `e` the public exponent and what you call `e` is actually `d` the private exponent.

Naming aside, your problem is that you're encrypting plaintext character code points that are larger than or equal to `n`. If they are, then you're actually encrypting not `ord("A")` (=65), but rather `ord("A") % n`. For small `n` as in your case this would lead to unrecoverable ciphertext:

```
>>> n = 3 * 17 # 51
>>> ord("A")
65
>>> ord("A") % n
14
```

And that is exactly that you would be able to decrypt. RSA is not something that can be used to encrypt arbitrarily big data. Normally, you would combine it with a secure and fast block cipher such as AES through [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem).

Comment: I limited my character set using a dictionary eg: letters = {a :1, b:2....}. So now its working fine. Thanks for your help :-)